# How to change the keyboard layout for a single application in Awesome WM?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, awesome

I've added [keyboard shortcuts to set the global keyboard layout](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/dc236912ab20356705c104743c64e7a763a86718/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L346-L347), but **how do I set it for a single application?** The reason I'd like to do this is that I'm used to QWERTY for gaming, and I'd rather not spend 10 minutes in every game to set up a custom layout. And I'd rather not have to switch layout when changing to other applications (which I do frequently), both for convenience and to avoid pressing the wrong shortcut.

Comment: In that case, why does it need to be for a single application? Why not change it with `setxkbmap` or whatever shortcut you have assigned to the switch, play your game, and then switch back when done?

Comment: [kbdd](https://github.com/qnikst/kbdd) should work under most WM, but there may be a better way with Awesome. Under Sawfish, I ended up running `xmodmap` on a window switch.

Answer (score 1):

To notice when a new app (your game) starts, use `client.connect_signal("manage", function(c) ...)`.  Then use `client.name` to see if it's your app ("kerbal-space-program", or whatever).  If both tests pass, apply your keyboard layout.

For extra tidiness, test `client.focus` to enable/disable that keyboard layout on the fly.

https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#